# JVM crash on solaris environment

Tags: java, crash, solaris

JVM Solaris crash.In 3 jvm crash in solaris with java 1.6.0_26-b03 the same signal handlers with same memory addresses are there in all the 3 crashes. What does it mean memory issue.Also there are so many signal handlers as below. Is that mean all these errors happened or just the dump of signals. Please help.

```
Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x9b1c70], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x9b1c70], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x23f948], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x23f948], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000, flags was changed from 0x0000000c, consider using jsig library
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x23f948], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x23f948], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0x868268], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x00000004
SIGHUP: [libjvm.so+0x868268], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x00000004
SIGINT: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0x868268], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x00000004
SIG39: [libjvm.so+0x86b9f8], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000008
SIG40: [libjvm.so+0x23f948], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
```

Comment: If you suspect a bug in Java 6 update 26, I suggest you try update 45 as many bugs have been fixed since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any given version of the JVM would establish the same set of signal handlers.  All the above means is that *if* a particular signal is raised, then that particular routine inside the JVM would be invoked.